# How I Can Delete Custom Post Type URL

Tags: custom-post-types

i create a Custom Post and i don't want them has a URL.

There is a URL like that = site.com/custom-slug/and-id-or-title [image]

and i don't want this, how i can do that?

Thank you already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand the question you're asking, you don't want your CPT to be directly available on the front-end.  If so, then just set `'public' => false` when you register the post_type.

Remember that various other args to [register_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) default to the value of `public` (e.g., `show_ui`), show when you set `'public' => false` you often times need to explicitly set those args to true, e.g.

```
$args = array (
    // don't show this CPT on the front-end
    'public' => false,
    // but do allow it to be managed on the back-end
    'show_ui' => true,
    // other register_post_type() args
    ) ;
register_post_type ('my_cpt', $args) ;
```

Comment: That's the thing i search. Thank you. I try this 'public' => false, but like that i lost this in admin panel but when i add this:  'show_ui' => true, i can see that on admin panel and there is not a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Sparrow Hawk is correct, as "public' affects several other args options.  So, while his solution will work, if you want to avoid having to make some other add'l changes because everything else is working, just set the arg you want to false, which is this one:

```
'publicly_queryable'  => false,
```

Add this line to the register_post_type function creating your custom post type and you won't have to make any other changes to the code.

ALSO.  Be sure to flush your permalinks after you make this change or you won't see any evidence of the change.

(to flush them, go to settings / permalinks and hit save)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
/**
 * Remove the slug from custom post type permalinks.
 */
function wpex_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME' ) ) || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;

}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpex_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Some hackery to have WordPress match postname to any of our public post types
 * All of our public post types can have /post-name/ as the slug, so they better be unique across all posts
 * Typically core only accounts for posts and pages where the slug is /post-name/
 */
function wpex_parse_request_tricksy( $query ) {

    // Only noop the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME', 'page' ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpex_parse_request_tricksy' );
```

Change "YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME" with your post type name.